# Storing all the outputs of for loop in a matrix python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy, matrix

```
from __future__ import division   
from math import *
import cmath   
import numpy as np

taup=3
eps = 0.000001;
i = 0;
del1 = 2*taup/150.;
x=[]
for tau in np.arange(-taup,taup,del1):
    i = i + 1;
    j = 0;
    fd = np.linspace(-5/taup,5/taup,151);
    val1 = 1. - abs(tau) / taup;
    val2 = pi * taup * (1.0 - abs(tau) / taup) * fd;
    x=np.hstack(abs( val1 * np.sin(val2+eps)/(val2+eps)))
```

The output x i am getting is only the last iteration output which is 1x151.
But i want all the iterations to stored in a matrix(here it will be 151x151).
I am n't able to get the last line correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append your 1D arrays to `x` and then `vstack` them:

```
    ...
    x.append(np.hstack(abs( val1 * np.sin(val2+eps)/(val2+eps))))

x = np.vstack(x)
```

Alternatively, pre-creating the results array can be faster:

```
taus = np.arange(-taup,taup,del1)
fd = np.linspace(-5/taup,5/taup,151);
x = np.empty((taus.size, fd.size))
for tau_i, tau in enumerate(taus):
# or: 
# for tau_i in range(taus.size):
#     tau = taus[tau_i]
    i = i + 1;
    j = 0;

    val1 = 1. - abs(tau) / taup;
    val2 = pi * taup * (1.0 - abs(tau) / taup) * fd;
    x[tau_i] = np.hstack(abs( val1 * np.sin(val2+eps)/(val2+eps)))
```

P.S. In fact, this code can be written without any `for` cycles, just in terms of array operations. That's an exercise for you.

Comment: For the 1st solution got the error "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append".                                                                        The 2nd one works fine.Thanks. Is there any other way of storing all the iteration values without creating a empty matrix.

Comment: That's weird, if you initialized ``x`` with ``[]`` in the first variant, you shouldn't have got such error.